# git parameter plugin : how to separate between 2 repositories on pipline job?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I m using git parameter plugin on pipeline job 
I need to get all branches from two different repositories 
this is my script

```
#!groovy
    node{
        checkout scm
        properties ([
                buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '3', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')),
                parameters([
                        [$class: 'GitParameterDefinition',
                         name: 'gitBranchCustomer',
                         description: ' branches projet 1',
                         type:'Branch',
                         branch: '',
                         branchFilter: '.*',
                         tagFilter:'*',
                         sortMode:'NONE',
                         defaultValue: '',
                         selectedValue:'NONE',
                         quickFilterEnabled: false],

                        [$class: 'GitParameterDefinition',
                         name: 'gitBranchCore',
                         description: 'branches projet 2',
                         type:'Branch',
                         branch: '',
                         branchFilter: '.*',
                         tagFilter:'*',
                         sortMode:'NONE',
                         defaultValue: '',
                         selectedValue:'NONE',
                         quickFilterEnabled: false],

                ])


        ])
        stage('select'){
            timeout(time:5){

                Environement = input( parameters: [ [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'production\npreprod\nrecette', description: '', name: 'Environement : '] ])
                println "Property: $Environement"
                if(Environement.equals("production")){
                    Mode_de_livraison = input( parameters: [ [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'Copie preprod\nRelivraison branche production', description: '', name: ' Mode de livraison : '] ])
                }else{
                    Mode_de_livraison = input(  parameters: [ [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'Full\nRelivraison branche pre-production', description: '', name: ' Mode de livraison : '] ])
                }
                println "Property: $Mode_de_livraison"
            }
        }

        //stage('checkout') {git branch: "master", credentialsId: '2d43b72d-fadc-446c-aaff-050a904b8ba9', url: 'https://github.com/mouadiativ/formation-test-1.git'}
    }
```

the problem is that it regroup all the branches in one parameter 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAchq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAchq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout all repos you want to work with at least once so Jenkins would save info about your SCMs. 
You can just use `git` DSL to checkout additional remote (besides "Pipeline from SCM"), insert it in pipeline and run pipeline once:

```
#!groovy
    node{
        git branch: "master", credentialsId: CRED_ID, url: URL
        checkout scm
        return // this will end build
        properties ([
                buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '3', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')),
                parameters([...
```

Then in `GitParameterDefinition` there is `useRepository` parameter, which you can set it in one git-parameter to `customer` and in other `core` (if those are names of your repos):

```
                parameters([
                        [$class: 'GitParameterDefinition',
                         name: 'gitBranchCustomer',
                         description: ' branches projet 1',
                         type:'Branch',
                         branch: '',
                         branchFilter: '.*',
                         tagFilter:'*',
                         sortMode:'NONE',
                         defaultValue: '',
                         selectedValue:'NONE',
                         quickFilterEnabled: false,
                         useRepository: 'customer'], // < ------ here

                        [$class: 'GitParameterDefinition',
                         name: 'gitBranchCore',
                         description: 'branches projet 2',
                         type:'Branch',
                         branch: '',
                         branchFilter: '.*',
                         tagFilter:'*',
                         sortMode:'NONE',
                         defaultValue: '',
                         selectedValue:'NONE',
                         quickFilterEnabled: false,
                         useRepository: 'core'] // < ------ and here

                ])
```